# Case Formula within a Formula field #errors out for one Record Type Opportunity while working for a different type

Tags: formula, opportunity, case, formula-field, record-type

The formula I am using is:

```
CASE($RecordType.DeveloperName, 
  "Opportunity_Layout_v1",
  Field1+Field2+Field3+Field4+Field5+Field6+
  Field7+Field8+Field9+Field10+Field11+Field12,
  "Opportunity_Layout_v2",
  Total_Budget_del_c * 1000 /  Cost__c ,
  NULL)
```

For some reason Opportunity Layout v1 returns an Error and populates the formula field with #Error! . I know that this error pops up usually for values being divided by 0, but nothing for the opportunity should be being divided by zero since it's just adding a bunch of fields.

Would having the second Opportunity Record Type marked as inactive cause the formula to jump to the division?

Please let me know if I can provide any more clarification.

Comment: You would most likely get that error if your either of your `Total__Budget_del__c` or `Cost__c` fields are null, or if `Cost__c` is 0.

Comment: I think the likely cause is that one (or more) of your 12 fields that you're summing for 'Opportunity_Layout_v1' is null. Is your formula set to treat blank values as blanks, or as 0?

Comment: @Derek F The formula is treating them as 0.

Comment: @DerekF So when I run this formula with just Opportunity v1 and without Opportunity v2, the numbers are adding up just fine. When I add the formula for Layout v2, the #Error! shows up again. Any ideas? While on Record Type Opportunity_Layout_V1, I don't want the math for Opportunity v2 to run.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Is it possible that Total__Budget_del__c also being a formula field that has a similar formula would cause this formula to zero out?

Comment: Is the double underscore between 'Total' and 'Budget' in `Total__Budget_del__c` a typo, or is that really how it is in your formula. Prefixing a field name with `someString__` is how Salesforce represents namespaces (for packages). That might cause issues (though it should prevent you from saving the formula unless 'Total' is a valid namespace in your org).

Comment: @DerekF Please disregard the double underscore, the field itself does not have double underscores. - I've edited the formula in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go around this issue by utilizing an IF formula instead of CASE. Please let me know if you think there is a simpler way to shorten this formula if, say, the org has 10 or 20 Record Types, but this is what worked:

`IF($RecordType.DeveloperName = "Opportunity_Layout_v1",Field1+Field2+Field3+etc,
IF($RecordType.DeveloperName ="Opportunity_Layout_v2",Total_Budget_del_c * 1000 /     Cost__c,
NULL
))`